# How do passport control officers know I have a PhD (UK passport)?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, customs-and-immigration

My UK passport doesn't list a title, but often when I go through passport control, the officer will say something like 'Thank you Doctor' or 'Have a good day doc'. How do they know I have a PhD? I'd also like to know what other information they see.

Comment: What title do you have on your driving licence?

Comment: What country is this? Doctor is a courtesy title in some parts of the world.

Comment: This has happened in Spain, Switzerland, and the UK

Comment: My driving license says Dr

Comment: Are you wearing a white coat and a stethoscope when you go through passport control?

Comment: @dothyphendot My theory was that British border officers would see your driving licence record, but that doesn't explain it if it happens in other countries too.

Comment: @Sneftel quite the opposite — Although perhaps I conform to the scruffy academic stereotype.

Comment: Have you looked at the data on your passport's electronic chip?  Maybe your title is listed there.  Or maybe Swiss and Spanish border guards also have access to UK license records (@MJeffryes).  Or maybe you're just more famous than you thought.  Or maybe your name is Henry Jekyll.

Comment: @phoog how would one look at the data? Certainly not famous!

Comment: An NFC-capable smartphone can read the chip with an appropriate app.

Comment: Are you listed as "Dr" on your flight tickets? Perhaps the border guard's screen cross-references your passport to API from the airline?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Inspection of my boarding pass reveals that it says Dr. So they must see that info when they read your passport? Curious what other info they see.

Comment: Whenever I buy tickets, I'm usually prompted for my title (Mr., Dr, etc...). Are you sure you didn't fill in Dr?

Comment: You can always you know ask them ;)

Comment: VTC: too speculative and open ended, per comments and OP's own note s/he includes the info when booking tickets, and where it occurred.